# Invalid or unexpected token in window terminal

Tags: node.js, quick-install-package

Invalid or unexpected token
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

iinstall  packages figlet and requires that but when i am trying to run in shownig error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.